# First three elements of arrary disappear in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have have written a PHP-Function that searches through a folder and adds the path and name of all files that begin with "WhatsApp Chat mit" to an array. If there's a subfolder, the function calls itself recursively. The problem is, that the first three elements of the array always disappear, the rest stays okay. It doesn't matter which elements are the first three, it's always the same. If I echo the filenames and paths directly in the loop, the first three elements are outputted, but in an array, they disappear. Firstly, I thought the maximum size of the array is reached, but this isn't the problem.

Any idea?

```
function readDirectory($path, $data) {
    $rawData = scandir($path);
    foreach($rawData AS $key => $item) {
        if($item[0] == ".") {
            unset($data[$key]);
            continue;
        } else {
            if(is_dir($path."/".$item)) {
                $data = readDirectory($path."/".$item, $data);
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 17) == "WhatsApp Chat mit") {
                $url = urlencode($path."/".$item);
                $name = substr($item, 17, -4);
                $data[] = [$name, $url];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Do the items that disappear start with the dot `.` character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping `$rawData` array and removing from `$data` array.

If first three elements in `$rawData` startr with dot, no matter what elements are in `$data`, they will always be removed.

```
function readDirectory($path, $data) {
    $rawData = scandir($path);
    foreach($rawData AS $key => $item) {
        if($item[0] == ".") {
            unset($data[$key]); // <-- Remove THIS
            continue;
        } else {
            if(is_dir($path."/".$item)) {
                $data = readDirectory($path."/".$item, $data);
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 17) == "WhatsApp Chat mit") {
                $url = urlencode($path."/".$item);
                $name = substr($item, 17, -4);
                $data[] = [$name, $url];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

It could be refactored like this:

```
function readDirectory($path, $data) {
    $rawData = scandir($path);
    foreach($rawData AS $key => $item) {
        if($item[0] !== ".") {
            if(is_dir($path."/".$item)) {
                $data = readDirectory($path."/".$item, $data);
            } elseif(substr($item, 0, 17) == "WhatsApp Chat mit") {
                $url = urlencode($path."/".$item);
                $name = substr($item, 17, -4);
                $data[] = [$name, $url];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```